# Window Manager scriptable in Clojure

Tags: clojure

### Goal

I want a WindowManager (for Linux) that I can script in Clojure.

### Question:

Is there any existing window manager: XMonad, AwesomeWM, Ion, XFce4, ... that allows itself to be queried and controlled via some external interface (TCP port, Unix socket, ...) ? Basically anything that would let me completely control the WM externally.

This seems like a slightly easier approach than embedding a JVM into one of these WMs.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe start here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:X_window_managers_extensible_by_scripting

Answer (score 3):

You can try stumpwm ( http://www.nongnu.org/stumpwm/). It's written in common lisp and can be controlled even via slime.